# Email table in html but format first column as date

Tags: javascript, email, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got the below code which sends the data from a specific sheet to the email address when there is data on the sheet (A1 = "Date"). Only trouble I'm having is how to format the first column as a date. Currently, it defaults to the full format (e.g. `Tue Jul 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`   ). Would prefer `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
function email_table() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('reminders');
  var ob='';
  var kl='';
  var h=[];
  var row1='';
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data)


 if(data[0][0]=='Date'){
    Logger.log('valid')
    var l = data[0].length
    //Logger.log(l)
    data.forEach(function(row){

      for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){
        ob=ob + '<td>'+row[i]+'</td>'
        if(i==(l-1)){
          h.push('<tr>'+ob+'</tr>')
          ob=''
        }
      }
    });
     //Logger.log(h)
     h.map(function(v){
       kl=kl+v
     })
     //Logger.log(kl)
     row1='<table style="width:100%;height:300;">'+ kl + '</table>'
     Logger.log('done');

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'abc@cde.com',
    subject: 'Task',
    htmlBody: row1,
  });
  } else{
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
function email_table() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('reminders');
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table style="width:100%;height:300;">';
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  if(hdrA[0][0]=='Date'){
    data.forEach(function(r,i){
      if(i==0){
        html+='<tr>';
        r.forEach(function(c){html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>',c);});
        html+='</tr>';
      }else {
      r.forEach(function(c,j){
        if(j==0) {
          html+='<tr>';
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(c), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
          html+='</tr>';
        }else {
          html+='<tr>';
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>',c);
          html+='/<tr>';
        }
        });
      } 
    });
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: 'abc@cde.com',subject: 'Task',htmlBody: html});
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are already formatted in Google Sheets, instead of `getValues()` use `getDisplayValues()`.

The above because `getValues()` returns JavaScript Date objects while `getDisplayValues()` returns strings the values displayed in Google Sheets as strings.